# Problem with function and buttons in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Today I have a tricky (for me at least) question. There is a bug in my code, I don't know how to eliminate it. Basically I'm creating a simple Form in JavaScript as an homework, and I encountered this problem.

I have to enter my age in this form, and for now it's all ok. But I have to enter it twice: one with an `<input>` tag and one with a popup window. I can  input the value in the `<input>` tag just fine, but when I'm trying to input the value by the prompt(), it "resets" the script, so I lose the value in the `<input>` object.

I need a way to store these information somewhere, or stop the prompt() from deleting these values or resetting the page.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
        body {padding: 20px;}
    </style>
    <script>
        var eta_btn;
        function eta_controllo(eta_btn) {
            eta_btn = Number(prompt("Inserisci la tua età"));
            console.log(eta_btn);
        }
        function profession() {
            var temp = document.getElementById("select").selectedIndex; 
            if (temp == 0) {
                document.getElementById("lavoratore_txt").style.display = "";
                document.getElementById("studente_txt").style.display = "none";
            } else if (temp == 1) {
                document.getElementById("studente_txt").style.display = "";
                document.getElementById("lavoratore_txt").style.display = "none";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("studente_txt").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("lavoratore_txt").style.display = "none";
            }
        } 
        function send_to_server() {
            if (!(eta_btn == document.getElementById("età").value)) {
                alert("Le due età inserite non sono concordi");
                return false;
            } 
            else if (eta_btn == document.getElementById("età").value && eta_btn < 14) {
                alert("Hai meno di 14 anni!");
                return false;
            } else if (confirm("Sicuro di aver scelto la provincia " + document.querySelector('input[name="città"]:checked').value)) 
                alert("Dati inviati correttamente");
            else {
                alert("Errore");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <p>NOME</p>
        <input placeholder="scrivi qui il tuo nome" type="text"><br><br>
        <p>PASSWORD</p>
        <input placeholder="scrivi qui la tua password" type="text"><br><br>
        <p>ETA'</p>
        <input placeholder="scrivi qui la tua età" type="text" id="età">
        <button onclick="eta_controllo()">CONTROLLO</button><br><br>
        <input name="città" type="radio">GENOVA<br>
        <input name="città" type="radio">SAVONA<br>
        <input name="città" type="radio">IMPERIA<br>
        <input name="città" type="radio">LA SPEZIA<br><br>
        <select name="" id="select" onchange="profession()">
            <option value="lavoratore">Lavoratore</option>
            <option value="studente">Studente</option>
            <option value="disoccupato">Disoccupato</option>
        </select>
        <p id="studente_txt" style="display: none">Vai a studiare!</p><br>
        <textarea id="lavoratore_txt" style="display: none;" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br><br>
        <button>ANNULLA TUTTO</button>
        <button onclick="send_to_server()">INVIA AL SERVER</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you passing `eta_btn` into the `eta_controllo()` function?

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to add `type="button"` to the button.
The default type of button is `"submit"`, so when you click it, it will submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you already taken a look at this link?
It could be ulile in my opinion ..
there are no global variables to manage the memories ..
The Localstorage of the browser.
I hope I have been of help .. good studyhttps://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp